# Strange error on Excel Workbook input

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, excel-interop

For the current code:

```
 String currentPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
        op.InitialDirectory = currentPath;
        if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            currentPath = op.FileName;
        else
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Failed to Load Workbook";
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Visible = true;
        }

        Workbook wb = new Workbook(excel.Workbooks.Open(currentPath));
```

I recieve the error:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  Message=Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
  Source=mscorlib
  ErrorCode=-2147221164

All I want is a predefined workbook to add worksheets to

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suppose that in your code the fullname of Workbook is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook, and that excel is an instance of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application.

If this is the case your code can't work because Workbook is an interface, and interfaces do not have constructors. You have to ask the excel application to create the workbooks for you, and in your case you have to simply write:

```
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(currentPath);
```

In a similar way, if you want to create a new empty workbook, you should write:

```
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
```

Comment: Amazingly this worked for me! I spent hours on this and everyone was trying to say that it was due to 64-bit/32-bit build mode and I had mine set the way it was all supposed to and still had the issue but this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about your error but I have done something similar like this:

```
 _app = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook wb = _app.Workbooks.Open(currentPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

Right click to your Solution and change Platform to x86
Rebuild your solution...
Good luck to you!